# need to write trigger on activity (Task and event)

Tags: apex, trigger, activities

I have following requirement,

```
Update Activity “Type” field with following:
Type = Call, if Subject starts with "Call" case-insensitive.
Type = Email, if Subject starts with "Email" case-insensitive.
Type = Task, for other Subject.
Type = Meeting, for all Events.
```

i have only one confusion that do i need to write 2 triggers for this like one for task and one for event

i have written trigger on task like

```
trigger updateTypeFieldOnTask on Task (before update,before insert) {
    List<task> taskList = new List<task>();
    for(task t: trigger.new) {
        if( t.Subject.startsWithIgnoreCase('Email')){
            t.type = 'Email';
        }
        else if(t.Subject.startsWithIgnoreCase('Call')){
            t.type = 'Call';
        }
        else if(t.Subject.startsWithIgnoreCase('Other')){
            t.type = 'Task';
        }
        taskList.add(t);
    }
}
```

it completes the 1st 3 requirement but for 4th requirement i.e
**Type = Meeting, for all Events.**
do i need to write another trigger for event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set fields on `Event`, you need a trigger on `Event`.

```
trigger Event on Event (before insert, before update)
{
    // implementation
}
```

However, all of the functionality you have been asked to build can be achieved via **`Workflow Rule Field Update`**, so you should go the declarative route here rather than adding code.